# Verilog with cocotb : assign statement

Tags: python, verilog, fpga, iverilog, cocotb

My Verilog code is an adder that just uses `assign sum = a+b`. The problem is that, while running it using `cocotb`, `sum` remains unknown, though `a` and `b` have valid values.

When I make `sum` a `reg` type, it works.

```
`timescale 1 ns / 1 ps

module adder(input [7:0] a,
        input [7:0] b,
        output reg  [7:0] sum,
        output [7:0] sum2);

    assign sum2=a+b;        // Trouble is here
    always@(a,b) begin
        sum=a+b;            // This works
    end

`ifdef COCOTB_SIM
    initial begin
        $dumpfile("adder.vcd");
        $dumpvars();
    end
`endif
endmodule
```

[image: gtkwave output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is actually caused by a bug in Icarus present in v0.9.7.

If you upgrade to the latest development version you'll find that a continuous assignment works fine. Other simulators also handle the continuous assignment fine.

If you're stuck on that version of Icarus you can workaround it by putting the assignment inside a process, as you discovered.

Comment: I take it the waveform image apparently showing a Gtkwave windows clued you in to the use of Icarus?

Comment: @user1155120 GTKWave is a giveaway, but a few people have also hit this issue.  Unfortunately most of the repositories for popular Linux distributions still provide Icarus v0.9.7

Comment: @Chiggs Hello Chris, I created the new tag [tag:cocotb], because there are more and more cocotb related questions and answers at SO. Maybe you want to subscribe to it.

Comment: @Paebbels thanks for that, will subscribe and try and help folks out where I can